# How to read lines from a file (.txt, .asm)

Tags: c

Like my input would be stored in a .txt/.asm file, and the input is kind of like this:

```
MOV Ri,Rj
MVI Ri,X
LOAD Ri,X(Rj)
STORE Ri,X(Rj)
```

So, I need to read them line by line and also store these. What is the best way to do this? Like I have checked [fscanf](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). But it seems like it will handle cases best when there is data of fixed format, like `(Hi, 2) (Bye, 3) (Hello, 4)`. But how should I go about handling my case? It should be able to read the entire line and then stop after the input finishes.

I apologize in advance if something like this has been asked earlier, but I couldn't find a question which matched what I asked.

Comment: `fgets` . Or, if you can use Posix interfaces, `getline`.

Comment: @rici So, I basically used freopen to redirect my stdin, and then used readline to read each line. Readline basically reads the lines and also allocates the required size using malloc internally. But, this works in UNIX systems only if I remember correctly. For getline, I need to allocate a buffer before, this isn't an issue as such, but does getline also have a similar implementation, where it uses malloc to do this thing?

Comment: You need to read the `getline` manpage more carefully. It *allows* you to preallocate the buffer but does not require you to do so. The most common usage is to initialise the buffer pointer to `NULL` and the size to 0, and then let `getline` manage it. That lets you reuse the same allocation, although again you are free to use the interface as you see fit.

Comment: `readline` is really intended for interactive input. And, as you say, it's not portable. There are freely available `getline()` implementations, so it can be used cross-platform.

Comment: Do you act on it as soon as you get a line and then discard, or, `fread` could be an option, if you need to read the whole file?

Comment: What is wrong about `fgets()`? You seem to drop it too early.